# SQLite query that contains special characters

Tags: android, sqlite

I have to build SQLite database where I store some strings which has some special character, for most of the cases it is working find except this one

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE use_id = 3B:02
```

It throws this errors

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ":02": syntax error (code 1):
```

How can I handle this when this "3B:02" is variable

Here is my query

```
selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DataBaseHelper.TABLE_COM + " WHERE "
                + DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_USER_ID + " = " + value;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String literal values in SQL need to be in `'single quotes'`.

However, it's better to use `?` placeholders for literals and bind the values, e.g.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DataBaseHelper.TABLE_COM + " WHERE "
            + DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?", new String[] { value });
```

Comment: but is not it requies to have minimum API level 16 ?

Comment: `rawQuery(String,String[])` has been there since API level 1. There's another overload of it that was added in 16.